# Prior to risky uninstall, pull one disk of raid 1 as a fallback?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, raid

I have to deal with a windows 2003 std server that has not been taken care of for years. It has an old, unsupported version of McAfee anti virus enterprise installed on it that is intermittently going nuts and taking over the cpu. I need to uninstall it. McAfee regards the software as end of life and is not available as a resource.

I am concerned that when I uninstall the anti virus software it could make a mess and possibly result in a server that won't boot or something of that order. There are backups from ntbackup of the server, but there is no way to test a restore short of just doing it.

The server is an IBM eServer xSeries 226 with hardware raid 1 (two mirrored disks). I was wondering if a fairly safe approach to this uninstall event would be to remove one disk prior to the uninstall, and if all succeeds, reintroduce the disk. On the other hand, if the uninstall results in a broken server, I could remove the disk that participated in the uninstall, and then boot from the disk that was pulled before the uninstall. Is this a reasonable approach?

I have never pulled a disk from this box so I don't really know what "it" will do when in the scenario above I reintroduce the 2nd disk. I suppose at boot time a screen would appear asking which disk it should 'go' with?

It's using Adaptec AIC-7902B HostRAID, with Adaptec AIC-7902B Ultra320 SCSI.

I not a raid wiz that's for sure, so I don't know if what I asked above is completely absurd, or reasonable. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not a bad idea, but maybe instead of pulling the disk take a full machine disk backup (use something like CloneZilla, may have to check on RAID support though).

Comment: Personal favourite is to use Clonezilla and then disk2vhd. Clonezilla is better for true bare metal, but disk2vhd lets to get easy file access via a .vhd disk image

Answer (score 2):

As Tom suggested, the first thing you should do is get a full bare metal backup of your system using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/), [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/), or any other 3rd party backup software.

Now when it comes time to break the raid, if the removal was successful **do not** just reinsert the other disk. Wipe it including the partition table then rebuild the Raid 1.